# Proof of a limit as X tends towards 0

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

Is this a valid proof for to show that the limit of $1/(x+1)$ tends to $1$ as $x$ tends to $0$?

[image]

Comment: If $-1<x<0$ is $\left|\frac{x}{1+x}\right|\leq |x|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ given.

we look for $\delta>0$ such that

$$|x|<\delta\implies |\frac{x}{1+x}|<\epsilon$$

as $x$ is near zero, we can add the condition $-\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{1}{2}$  which yields to  $|x+1|>\frac{1}{2}$

and $|\frac{x}{x+1}|<2|x|$.

so, if we take $\delta=\min(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2})$

we will have

$$|x|<\delta\implies |\frac{x}{1+x}|<2|x|<2\delta<\epsilon$$
qed.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is wrong - it is not true that $$\left|\frac{x}{1+x}\right|\leq |x|$$ because $x$ can be negative, like $x=\frac{-1}{2}$, then $\left|\frac{x}{1+x}\right|=1>\frac{1}{2}=|x|$.